# How to compare two image in Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, comparison

I have two images, I wanted to check that both images are similar and if yes then how much similar in percentage, i heard that opencv is a great library for image processing thing but still i could not find.

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731362/image-color-comparison-in-objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775323/how-to-compare-two-images-with-iphone-sdk